# Unable to select the text in android phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I want to get selected text from android phonegap. I have some text in htmlpage when i selected some text i want to get it back and change the color of  selected text.But i am unable to select text. My text data is in div.Please help me.  Here is my code.

```
    <body> 
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">    
    </div>
   <div  id="log">
  </div>
 </body>
 <script>
  $.ajax({
type:'GET',
url: 'http://10.0.2.2:7080/example/TranscriptVieww',
dataType:'text',
success: function(data){
$( "#log" ).append(data);
 }, 
error: function(){
   alert("There was an error loading the data.");
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in a browser but not sure about mobile webview. Give it a shot:

```
function GetSelectedText () {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = window.getSelection ();
        //range is the selected text
    }
}
```

Wait... Are you talking about user selected text, programmatically selected text, or just all the text from the "log" div?  The above will work for user selected and programmatically selected text but not getting all content from a div. If you just want all content from the log div just do a simple innerHTML call:

```
var selectedText = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Editing for clarity and a question. Stand by

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this javascript method to get selected content from any page.

var selectedText = getselectedcontent();

alert(selectedText);

--------------------------------

function getselectedcontent() {
    var selection = window.getSelection(); 
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
    if (range) { 
      var div = document.createElement('div'); 
      div.appendChild(range.cloneContents()); 
      return div.innerHTML; 
    } else {
      return "";
    }
}
```